# Negative margin in CSS works for element only if container element has set border or padding

Tags: html, css, border, padding, margin

According to Mozilla docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#margin
a negative margin should works fine.

But example provided by Mozilla has `border` set on `.container` element.
Turns out that negative margin works only if `border` or `padding` is set on the container element.

If a container doesn't have `border` or `padding` set, then the negative margin on the child element doesn't work.

Is it a bug or a feature?
It works quite counterintuitively.

I can't find any rational explanation behind this behavior in the spec
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#mpb-examples

I reproduced this behavior in all major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Edge.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 200px auto;

/* border or padding is required for negative margin to work */
/* border: 1px solid transparent; */
   padding: 1px;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;

  margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

```
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 200px auto;

/* border or padding is required for negative margin to work */
/* border: 1px solid transparent; */
/* padding: 1px; */
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;

  margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/adrianbienias/pen/MWJNYyw?editors=1100

Comment: the duplicate deal with positive margin but the same also apply to negative. TL;DR: your are facing margin-collapsing

Comment: The "problem" disappears when setting conainer's border because margin collapsing happens only with elements without borders.